# C# SQL Insert records or delete records by GridView

Tags: c#, sql, gridview, datagridview

I am using C# Visual Studio 2005 and SQL Server 2005.

I have a GridView table which shows a list of data from my SQL Server database.

I establish my connection via PageLoad method. E.g.:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [UserTable]";
        SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
    }
```

---

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    </asp:GridView>
```

However, I am trying to add a function for my Gridview table:

**To enable removal of records from the GridView via checkbox of each row of record and a remove button.**

The output I want is a checkbox for each row of data of the Gridview, and a 'Remove' button which delete all the records with their checkbox 'checked'.

May I know how can I approach to the outcome that I want?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">       
                    <Columns>
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                            <ItemTemplate>

                              <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" OnCheckedChanged="--your events--" runat="server" />
                                 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete"  runat="server" onclick="lnkDelete_Click"  Text="Delete"
                                 CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' ></asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

**on lnkDelete_Click event**

```
LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)sender;
 int stid = Convert.ToInt32(lnk.CommandArgument);
```

now you have id  of  table which is primary key and you put your delete code here.

Comment: Hi Mayur, may I know what do I need to change in your code to cater for myself? I don't see any delete sql queries in your code.

Comment: Does the CommandArgument stores the primary key? How can I grep the variable out and use it at my backend sql command?

Comment: in CommandArgument you can set primary key which is samename of columnname of your table

Comment: Thanks Mayur. However, I received the error that Input string is not in correct format. My primary key is in String, not in Int. What should my Convert. be?

Comment: Thanks Mayur. I clicked on the delete button but it says: Invalid syntax near '*'. My current sql statement: SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "DELETE * FROM [UserDB] where User = "+stid ;

Comment: remove  '*' from your command. "DELETE  FROM [AIXUserDB] where Employee = "+stid ;

Comment: Thanks Mayur, now it gave an error that says: Invalid column name 'primary-key-here'.

Comment: What is your primarykey column name?

Comment: My current sql statement is SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "DELETE FROM [UserDB]where Employee ="+stid; and I am receiving the error Invalid column name '900040'. (900040 is the UserID in the GridTable)

Comment: put this  <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete"  runat="server" onclick="lnkDelete_Click"  Text="Delete"
                                 CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Employee") %>' ></asp:LinkButton>

Comment: It seems to take my primary key as a column name ><

Comment: put  DELETE FROM [UserDB]where UserID ="+stid   and put CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserID") %>'